# How to create a hierarchical cluster using categorical and numerical data is R?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I want to create a hierarchical cluster to show types of careers and the balance that those who are in those careers have in their bank account.
I a dataset with two variables, job and balance:

```
              job balance
1       unemployed    1787
2         services    4789
3       management    1350
4       management    1476
5      blue-collar       0
6       management     747
7    self-employed     307
8       technician     147
9     entrepreneur     221
10        services     -88
```

I want the result to look like this:

[image]

Where A, B ,C etc are the job categories.

Can anyone help me start this or give me some help?

I have no idea how to begin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using the `dist`and `hclust` functions.

```
df <- read.table(text = "              job balance
1       unemployed    1787
2         services    4789
3       management    1350
4       management    1476
5      blue-collar       0
6       management     747
7    self-employed     307
8       technician     147
9     entrepreneur     221
10        services     -88")
```

`dist` computes the distance between each element (by default, the euclidian distance):

```
distances <- dist(df$balance)
```

You can then cluster you values using the distance matrix generated above:

```
clusters <- hclust(distances)
```

By default, hclust applies [complete-linkage clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering) to your data.
Finally, you can plot your results as a tree:

```
plot(clusters, labels = df$job)
```

Here, we clustered all the entries in your data frame, that's why some jobs are duplicated. If you want to have a single value per job, you can for example take the mean balance for each job using `tapply`:

```
means <- tapply(df$balance, df$job, mean)
```

And then cluster the jobs:

```
distances <- dist(means)
clusters <- hclust(distances)
plot(clusters)
```

You can then try to use other distance measures or other clustering algorithms (see `help(dist)` and `help(hclust)` for other methods).